# Is there a fine way to get file mime type / extension by a download link?

Tags: javascript, http

I need to get file extension from a download link, currently I'm using the following script (excerpt from React hook)

```js
// ...
useEffect(() => {
    /// ...
    void (async () => {
      try {
        setIsLoading(true);
        const response = await fetch(downloadLink);
        const blob = await response.blob();

        setFileExtension(fileExtensionByMimeType[blob.type]);
      } finally {
        setIsLoading(false);
      }
    })();
  }, []);
// ....
```

This code works, but the problem is that `response.blob()` takes time relatively to the file size, and I guess my solution is just bad.

Maybe there is some elegant way to solve my problem?

Comment: Does your service support head requests?

Comment: Yes, my service supports head requests

Comment: According to [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/blob), `blob()` reads the resource to completion. Are you sure you need `blob()`? Why don't you use the `.body` property?

Comment: Consider making a head request to get that data you need

Comment: I just can't figure out how do I get mime type either with the HEAD request or `.body` prop :( I've read about `response.body`, tried to console some data from ReadableStream - all I get is Unit8Array without any hints on mime type. And about HEAD request, I assume, my backend could send me back headers with mime type, but it doesn't

Answer (score 2):

My bad, just discovered that I have all the headers I need, I was confused with *empty* `headers` prop:

[image]

Turns out it's not empty and I can get my mime type by this code:

```js
const response = await fetch(downloadLink, { method: 'HEAD' });
const mimeType = response.headers.get('content-type');
```

Also, I think `HEAD` is appropriate here